# Not getting the range I want when plotting a function with Show

Tags: plotting

I have a problem with plotting a piecewise defined function with "Show". My code is

```
f1[u_] := Piecewise[
{{2/Sqrt[1 + u], u < 2},
{1/(Sqrt[1 + u*((u + Sqrt[-4 + u^2])/2)^3]) + 
 1/(Sqrt[1 + u*((u - Sqrt[-4 + u^2])/2)^3]), u >= 2}}]

p := Plot[f1[u], {u, 0, 10}]
enter code here

Show[p, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0.8, 2}}]
```

And the result is

[image]

btw. I use Show to plot this function with some Listplots, but the problem occurs also without the Listplots.

Interesting is also that when I define u from 0 to 5 in the definition of p, the resulting plot shows the entire function from 0 to 5 without problems ?
I hope u can help me finding the error

Comment: Try PlotRange-> All in the definition of p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when you do the plot first, when invoking `p`, it automatically chooses the `PlotRange`.

```
f1[u_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2/Sqrt[1 + u], 
    u < 2}, {1/(Sqrt[1 + u*((u + Sqrt[-4 + u^2])/2)^3]) + 
     1/(Sqrt[1 + u*((u - Sqrt[-4 + u^2])/2)^3]), u >= 2}}]

p := Plot[f1[u], {u, 0, 10}]
p
```

you get this
[image]

So later, when you do the `Show` command, it won't redraw the function where it didn't do so before.  Even though you've defined `p` with the `:=`, p is still invoked without the `PlotRange` option you feed to `Show'.

This should work for you

```
f1[u_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2/Sqrt[1 + u], 
    u < 2}, {1/(Sqrt[1 + u*((u + Sqrt[-4 + u^2])/2)^3]) + 
     1/(Sqrt[1 + u*((u - Sqrt[-4 + u^2])/2)^3]), u >= 2}}]

p := Plot[f1[u], {u, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
(*enter code here*)

Show[p, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0.8, 2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: wow thanks, i wouldn't have thought this could be a problem :)

Comment: Yeah, personally I wish that `PlotRange->All` was the default option for every kind of plot, since I find myself typing that all the time.

Comment: @JasonB try `SetOptions[#,PlotRange->All]&/@ {Plot, ListPlot, DateListPlot}`, adding other plot functions to the list as required.

Comment: @Verbeia, If I wanted that to happen all the time, should I add that line to the `init.m` file?

Comment: @JasonB yes, or a package in your Applications/Autoload path